# batch file errorlevel

Tags: file, batch-file

I want to Ensure  that my machine there are no version up on 2
So example I try to get 3 version  in the line below:

```
REG QUERY "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\zup\Product" /v 3
if ERRORLEVEL  0 ( //found 3
ECHO error.>>%LogFileName%
```

But when it try to get this field from the registry I get an error: 
“The system was unable to find the specified registry key or value”
So how I can to check it?

Comment: Try running as admin to permit access to hklm

Comment: I try but I get the same error,the value 3 relay don't exist in this path.but if it not found errorlevel 1 manage it?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is that Product is a ValueName.

If Product is the ValueName, you should be calling it like this:

`REG QUERY "HKLM\SOFTWARE\zup" /v Product`

this will echo the details of the ValueName Product

---

There is a problem with your if statement.

`IF ERRORLEVEL 0`
matches return codes equal to or greater than 0, which will always match.

To check for a missing ValueName use `IF ERRORLEVEL 1`

Noting that REG has two return code.

```
0 - Successful
1 - Failed
```

---

Here is some example code that checks if notepad has it's statusbar visable.

Notepad is the keyname and statusbar is the ValueName.

```
@echo off
setlocal

set statusbar=0
set query_command=reg query hkcu\software\microsoft\notepad /v statusbar

:: parse output of reg
for /f "tokens=1,2,3" %%a in ('%query_command%') do (
    :: search for line starting with statusbar
    if /i "statusbar"=="%%a" (
        :: parse hex into int
        set /a statusbar=%%c
        )
    )

if %statusbar% EQU 1 (
    echo notepad's status bar is visable
    ) else (
    echo notepad's status bar isn't visable
    )

endlocal
```